# Error: URL Personalization

Tags: email, html, error, content-builder, einstein-recommendations

I'm trying to customize my url by putting the recipient's email address as UTM in a hidden field but when I try to send, I get an error saying it's wrong, but I can't figure out what's wrong.
(the URL is inside a snippet of HTML code)

[image]EX: https://destination _url***&email=%%email%%***

where in **&email=%%email%%** is the problem
In other platform of mailing it works but here doesn't.

Comment: is email a field in your sending DE?

Comment: Yes, all the data I want to send is there, @EazyE